# Fill area with negativeColor in highcharts spline area graph

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I am working on spline area graph and I have a requirement in which I need to fill the area above the line with certain color rather than area under the line .
I tried using "negativeFillColor" and "threshold" option and [**here (Link To Fiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/developer_fiddle/s7353/) is what I am getting ..
RELEVANT CODE

```
series:{
        data : valueArray,
            negativeFillColor: seriesThsColor,
            threshold  : valueArray.max(),
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            ...
             }
```

What I want to do is to fill the complete area with the color rather that just upto the threshold .
[image]

Any Suggestions or alternate..?

Comment: Have you tried to add extra series (arearange type) ? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange

Comment: @SebastianBochan .. How is that going to help me ?

Comment: Allows to fill your area?